# Why is my stacked bar and line chart having different series assignments in VBA than from when I did it manually?

Tags: excel, vba, graph, stacked-bar-chart

I am trying to create a stacked bar chart with a line series on top of it. However when I move from creating the stacked chart manually to vba it changes the series to make the chart unusable for my purpose. It changes the categories I want on the x-axis to stacked sections, and the stacked categories to the x-axis sections.

Typically I work with data transfer and automated form filling, so I'm no expert at graph making in vba. I recorded the code below and adjusted it so it would fit my variable data range (n is the row category). It selects the correct data, just switches the axis.

```
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlColumnStacked).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Worksheets(name).Range("B1"), Worksheets(name).Range("B2").Offset(n - 1, 2))

    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(n + 1).name = "Takt"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(n + 1).Values = Range(Worksheets(name).Range("E1"), Worksheets(name).Range("E2").Offset(n - 1, 0))
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(n + 1).ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "Yamazumi"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Yamazumi"
```

Comment: "when i move from creating the stacked chart manually in vba" you mean when execute the recorded macro? Is the code you're running the one you posted or is it a part of it? Two pictures of "right" and "wrong" would be helpful

Comment: Yes, when I execute the code I get a different result. It is not the full code, but the code above just creates a table for this section of code to pull off of.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/j9c60ec  This has the pictures of the right graph, wrong graph, and the table that the code creates to show the format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'i use Me instead WorkSheets(name) to reproduce...

Sub TestGraph()
   Dim n As Long
   'for the data in picture the n have to be 2
   n = 2
   'From the picture of "right" graph: you don't need headers, so B1 => B2
   'also need range B2:D4 so Offset(n-1, 2) => Offset(n, 2)
   'AND FIRST select the data
   Me.Range(Me.Range("B2"), Me.Range("B2").Offset(n, 2)).Select
   
   Me.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlColumnStacked).Select
   'ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range(Worksheets(name).Range("B1"), Worksheets(name).Range("B2").Offset(n - 1, 2))


    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(n + 1).Name = "Takt"
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(n + 1).values = Me.Range(Me.Range("E2"), Me.Range("E2").Offset(n, 0))
    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(n + 1).ChartType = xlLine
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.text = "Yamazumi"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.text = "Yamazumi"
End Sub
```

now try not to work with "Select" or "Selected" anything... It is good practice to explicitly mention the object e.g.

```
Sub TestGraph()
   Dim n As Long, shp As Object
   n = 2
   Me.Range(Me.Range("B2"), Me.Range("B2").Offset(n, 2)).Select

   Set shp = Me.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlColumnStacked)

   With shp.Chart
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .FullSeriesCollection(n + 1).Name = "Takt"
    .FullSeriesCollection(n + 1).values = Me.Range(Me.Range("E2"), Me.Range("E2").Offset(n, 0))
    .FullSeriesCollection(n + 1).ChartType = xlLine
    .ChartTitle.text = "Yamazumi"
    End With
End Sub
```

Use the Headers and remove the early "Select" of data:

```
Sub TestGraph()
   Dim n As Long, shp As Object
   n = 2
   'Me.Range(Me.Range("B1"), Me.Range("B2").Offset(n, 2)).Select
   Set shp = Me.Shapes.AddChart2(297, xlColumnStacked)
   With shp.Chart
    .SetSourceData Source:=Me.Range(Me.Range("B1"), Me.Range("B2").Offset(n, 2))
    .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .FullSeriesCollection(n + 1).Name = "Takt"
    .FullSeriesCollection(n + 1).values = Me.Range(Me.Range("E2"), Me.Range("E4"))
    .FullSeriesCollection(n + 1).ChartType = xlLine
    .ChartTitle.text = "Yamazumi"
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly. I needed to change the n+1 in the series collection to 3 so it wouldn't error when I had a different number of stations, but it works exactly how I wanted it to.